# Dpkg keep saying that need to --configure -a while trying for network issues on Inspiron 1545

Tags: configuration, dpkg

I've just installed ubuntu for the first time on a computer (version 12.10). I can't figure out how to get a wired connection to work OR a wireless connection.

I've read similar problems, and I've tried the other recommended fixes (at least those that I could figure out), and none of them have worked. Most of the time the terminal just gives me an error when I try to type in the message others recommend.

I see a lot of people recommending to type this in:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source

This gives me an error message that says:

E: dpkg wasa interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So, outside of recommending that fix, what are some other options? I'm using another computer to ask this question.

Also, I'm running from a flash driver right now. Is that a problem? Should I try to install an older version. I'd like to install on my computer, but I can't without an internet connection...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do what ever else first you have to resolve the home issue. just open your terminal and type as

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

**What it will do ?**

```
 --configure package...|-a|--pending
          Reconfigure an unpacked package. If -a  or  --pending  is  given
          instead  of  package, all unpacked but unconfigured packages are
          configured.

          Configuring consists of the following steps:

          1. Unpack the conffiles, and at the same time back  up  the  old
          conffiles, so that they can be restored if something goes wrong.

          2. Run postinst script, if provided by the package.
```

after fixing the above issue,  you can install/remove

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. It's taken me a few days to get back to working on this, and your recommendations did something, but I still can't add the Broadcom STA Wireless driver. When I try to activate it, it says "Sorry, the installation of this driver failed. Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log" After running your recommendations I got two warnings. "failed to detect canonical device of overlayfs" and "could not determine root device from /etc/fstab." I'm not sure what either of those means.

Should I just try to install an older version?

Comment: Seems to be yes. Something Went wrongly. Check that log file for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works then just try this:

open a terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute:

```
    $ sudo (jockey-gtk &)
```

It will automatically search all available proprietary drivers and try to fix it and then  don't forget to restart your system.

Comment: and don't forget to restart your system.